# Flash library symbol to Flex converter

Tags: apache-flex

Is there a tool that will convert an exported Flash library element (ie Component/MovieClip) to an AS3 class with Flex syntax, ie[Embed(source="graphic.png")]

Thanks,

Philip

Answer (score 0):

Yes by doing this for example

```
[Embed(source='SWFFileName.swf', symbol='symbolName')]
[Bindable]
public var imgCls:Class;
```

and then for example :

```
<mx:Image source="{imgCls}" width="300" height="300"/>
```